# apply the same mtext to every page

Tags: r, histogram

I have multiple plots across multiple pages, how do I provide the same mtext for all page? below is an example data-set:

```
bootData <- lapply(seq(1,24), function(x) rnorm(50))
names(bootData) <- c("0", "2", "4", "6", "8", "10", "15", "20", "30", "40", "45", 
"50", "55", "60", "65", "70", "80", "85", "90", "92", "94", "96", 
"98", "100")
```

Plot the data

```
pdf(file = "test.pdf", width = 11.5, height = 8.5)
par(mar=c(5,4,3,2), oma=c(3,3,1,3), mfrow = c(2,3))
lapply(names(bootData), function(x) hist(bootData[[x]], main = paste("Histogram of", x)))

mtext("Error per label", side = 1, line = 1, outer = TRUE,  col = "firebrick")
dev.off()
```

I would like the mtext "Error per label" to appear in every page. With the above code it only appears in the last page.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: your `mtext` is outside the `lapply`. include it within the `lapply` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pdf(file = "test.pdf", width = 11.5, height = 8.5)
par(mar=c(5,4,3,2), oma=c(3,3,1,3), mfrow = c(2,3))
lapply(names(bootData), function(x){ 
hist(bootData[[x]], main = paste("Histogram of", x))
mtext("Error per label", side = 1, line = 1, outer = TRUE,  col = "firebrick")
})
dev.off()
```